# insert N row for tbl_summary categorical variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to include the total number of non-missing observations used to calculate the percentage of categorical variables as its own row just like for continuous variables. I am aware of the "{n} / {N} ({p}%)" option but this clutters the table a bit. If I add `"{N}"` to the all_categorical statistic, I get the following error message: `! The statistic requested for variable 'grade' cannot have length greater than 1.` I have seen the options of adding a new column [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676585/gtsummary-split-add-n-between-groups) but some of the tables I am working with are wide.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, age, grade)

trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = list(
      all_continuous2() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}", 
                            "{mean} ({sd})",
                            "{median} ({p25}, {p75})"),
      all_categorical() ~ c(#"{N}",
                            "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")
    ),
    digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(0, 1, 1)),
    label = grade ~ "Tumor Grade",
    
    missing = "no",
  )
```

**Current output:**

[image: Current output]

Thanks for any help!